# Checking if current user has db_backupoperator role / permissions

Tags: sql-server

For our backup software I'm trying to add a check if the user has enough permissions to create a backup.

When I create a login `Test` for a database and give it the `db_backupoperator` role for that database, how do I check for that role?

I tried:

`SELECT name as 'DatabaseName', has_dbaccess(name) as 'HasAccess' FROM sys.databases`

This is always `0` for each database (except `master`, `tempdb` and `msdb`).

When I do:

`SELECT name as 'DatabaseName', HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(name, 'DATABASE', 'CREATE BACKUP') as 'HasAccess' FROM sys.databases`

It results in `NULL` for each database.

When I do:
`SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER ( 'db_backupoperator')`

I get `0` because I probably don't have permissions to view the permission tables even though I know the user has that role assigned.

Any other way?

Comment: I must admit, a role with the prefix `sp_` is an odd choice, as the prefix is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures.

Comment: I never thought about that. For our backup solution we have a single user called "Backup" which has access to all databases and is assigned the role "sp_backupoperator", which is a standard SQL server role. Is this not the recommended approach?

Comment: `sp_backupoperator` isn't a default role. Are you thinking of `db_backupoperator`? If you have a role called `sp_backupoperator` that is a custom role.

Comment: That's my mistake, you are right it's db_backupoperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME()` approach works for me, but I needed to change the permission name to `BACKUP DATABASE`. I got the name of the permission from [the documentation for database-level GRANTs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Note, there's also a `BACKUP LOG` permission if you need to check that as well.

TL;DR -

```
SELECT name as 'DatabaseName', 
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(name, 'DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE') as 'HasAccess' 
FROM sys.databases;
```

As for the `IS_ROLEMEMBER()` approach, that works for me unchanged. I see in the comments that you had a misrecollection about the name of the actual role. Is it possible that that's an explanation for the behavior that you were seeing?

All that said, I'd personally prefer the `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME()` approach. Regardless of *how* the permission was granted, that will expose whether or not the current user/login has it.

Comment: I delete the user from all databases and re-added it again and now it seems to work. I must added the user disconnected from the actual login user and that's why it didn't work. Now both methods work yes!